# A quasi-concave functional plus a linear functional is a quasi-concave functional

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

If I have a positive linear functional $f$ and a positive quasi-concave functional $g$, then is $f+g$ a quasi-concave functional?

I figure that I need to show that $(f+g)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \min((f+g)(x), (f+g)(y))$.

I can bring it to:
\begin{align*}
        (f+g)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) &= f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) + g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\\
        &= \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) + g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\\
        &\geq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) + \min\{g(x),g(y)\}\\
        &\geq \min\{f(x),f(y)\} + \min\{g(x),g(y)\}
\end{align*}

However, I can't proceed beyond this point to show that the required condition is satisfied.